# What's wrong here? - ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Circle' with no type

Tags: c++, class, iso

maybe you can help me get this right.
I have a class that is used to draw a circle, but the compiler sends me this message:

```
In file included from ./Includes.h:19,
                 from ./Circle.h:8,
                 from ./Circle.cpp:5:
./GameApp.h:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Circle' with no type
./GameApp.h:24: error: expected ';' before '*' token
```

Here is the GameApp.h:

```
#include "Includes.h"

class GameApp {

public:
 GameApp();
 ~GameApp();
 void Render();

protected:
 void InitGU();
 bool Controls();

 void *dList;  // display List, used by sceGUStart
 void *fbp0;  // frame buffer

 Circle* circle;
};
```

The Include.h looks like this:

```
//************************************************************************
//                              Includes.h
//************************************************************************

#include <malloc.h>     //For memalign()
#include <pspkernel.h>
#include <pspdisplay.h>
#include <pspdebug.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psprtc.h>             // for the timer/fps functions
#include <pspctrl.h>
#include <math.h>

// GU
#include <pspgu.h>
#include <pspgum.h>

// Custom
#include "GameApp.h"
#include "Circle.h"


//************************************************************************

// Definitions
#define BUF_WIDTH (512)
#define SCR_WIDTH (480)
#define SCR_HEIGHT (272)

#define sin_d(x) (sin((x)*M_PI/180))
#define cos_d(x) (cos((x)*M_PI/180))
#define tan_d(x) (tan((x)*M_PI/180)) 

//************************************************************************

// structs, datatypes...
#ifndef VERTEX_TYPE_
#define VERTEX_TYPE_
typedef struct {
    unsigned int color;
    float x, y, z;
} vertex;
#endif
```

And the Circle.h

```
//************************************************************************
//                              Circle.h
//************************************************************************

#ifndef CIRCLE_H_
#define CIRCLE_H_

#include "Includes.h"

class Circle {

public:
    Circle(float r1);
    ~Circle();
    void Render();

    float r;
    float x, y;
    float vx, vy;

protected:
    vertex* vertices;
    int n;

};

#endif
```

Comment: I removed the C tag. Putting C on a question like this is thoroughly ridiculous. Also, there's nothing wrong with that class. It would be useful to see the actual code.

Comment: Is **GameApp.h** included in **Includes.h**?  Do your headers have inclusion guards?  Do you have a circular inclusion problem?

Comment: Are you sure your Circle.h is a valid header file -- have you successfully compiled something using it? Perhaps you've forgotten the semicolon at the end of the class declaration?

Comment: It at least might help to see the code containing the definition of your `Circle` class.

Comment: Please post Circle.h . And look for mismatched }'s in any of your include files.

Comment: @James must be right -- Circle.h #includes GameApp.h, as shown by the original compiler message, and GameApp.h presumably #includes Circle.h but that is useless due to the redundant include guard.

Comment: You forgot to add include guard to Include.h.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do *not* use *one-massive-include-to-include-everything* (except for precompiled headers).  It will almost certainly result in headaches.

*Include what you need*, and no more.  It will solve your problem.

You can forward declare `Circle`, as [DanDan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356700/whats-wrong-here-iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-circle-with-no-type/3356741#3356741), but fixing your inclusion problem will help you more in the long run.

Comment: what would you say about the "defines" in the Include.h or the type definition of vertex?

Answer (score 2):

You may have cyclic inclusion.  Use a forward declaration:

```
class GameApp { 
class Cicle;
...
```

Comment: You've just forward declared class Cicle [sic] as a nested class within GameApp.  The compiler will then go looking for implementation of a class GameApp::Cicle.  The forward declaration should be outside (and before) the definition of GameApp.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your make file to make sure the build is in the right order then, include both .h in each .h finial try combining the class if there both simple. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Includes.h includes GameApp.h before including Circle.h.  So Circle is not yet defined the first time it encounters the definition of GameApp.  Like DanDan says forward declare Circle.

Answer (score 1):

In Includes.h, you need to move the `#include "Circle.h"` ahead of the `#include "GameApp.h"`.  Better yet, just include Circle.h directly from GameApp.h.  Each header file should include everything it needs to compile directly.

Answer (score 0):

@James is right -- Circle.h #includes GameApp.h, as shown by the original compiler message, and GameApp.h  #includes Circle.h via the poorly-thought-out "include-all" Includes.h, but that #include is useless due to the redundant include guard on Circle.h